# AWS RH9 - can't connect (works with other images)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I use Terraform to generate AWS EC2 instances, it's great and fast.
It works with all AlmaLinux but when I switch to the top 5 images : RH9, then nothing works anymore.

I have no way to know why because :
ssm-agent not installed by default in RH image, can't use ec2 console and worse : **SSH doesn't work anymore** :

`OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data generated/ssh_config2
debug1: generated/ssh_config2 line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: generated/ssh_config2 line 4: Applying options for 10.11.5.89
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xx.xx.xx is address
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec aws ssm start-session --target i-xxxxxxxxxx --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=22 --profile default --region eu-west-1
debug1: identity file C:\Users\doe.ssh\jd-key-pair.pem type 3
debug1: identity file C:\Users\doe\.ssh\jd-key-pair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2

An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation: i-xxxxxxxxxxx is not connected.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535`

Any idea why switching image doesn't work anymore (RH9 and AlmaLinux are same family) ?

Ty for your helps.
Because Terraform works fine for everything with AlmaLinux, I know everything defined well. The problem must come from the image, or from me :o)